# Can disable the time picker using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I downloaded one admin template that template has datetimepicker in that I want only date picker but I don't how to disable the time picker please help me how to fix these issues. I'll attach my class file and HTML code and same time I'll attach the time picker UI also.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Material Datetime Picker Css -->
<link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**This one they using footer**

```
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/momentjs/moment.js')}}"></script> <!-- Moment Plugin Js -->
<!-- Bootstrap Material Datetime Picker Plugin Js -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js')}}"></script>
```

**This is my HTML code**

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon">
                 <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i>
             </span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" placeholder="Please choose date & time...">
       </div>
   </div>
```

**[image: Next I attached my UI also]**

Comment: I don't want this time picker what is showing in the image I attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `time` param as false like:

```
$('.datetimepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ time: false });
```

[Demo Here](http://t00rk.github.io/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/)

Comment: Thank you so much It's working but a small UI issue came I'll fix this.